# Adjust view sizes in android for custom devices

Tags: android, layout, view, size

I have 3 custom made android devices.
First one has a 5 inch screen with 1280x800 res
Second has a 5 inch screen with 800x480 res
Third has 7 inch screen with 800x480 res

I tried giving sizes with dp, px and inches but it seems they cant support those screens properly with the same value (even inches seems to be not exact inches but translation to px eventually).

How can i use same code to properly adjust view sizes relatively to the screen size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as first, the correct measure unit to use is: dp for controls and sp for fonts.
These are normally for margin, paddings, widths, heights, and other attributes.
Also xml drawables can take advantage of pixel independency
Define your dimensions in a res/value/dimens.xml file (this is a PROPOSED standard name, you can call it whatever you like best), in order to have them referrable from all your code, instead of being hardcoded and often repeated in many files.
Then you must know that you should provide your graphics AT LEAST in **mdpi** resolution (**160 dpi**), which will be scaled up or down to match other resolutions.
Notice that I said **at least**.
For every resolution you are supporting, you should add a folder in your res path containing the graphics at the corresponding density for that resolution.
this means that you will have, let's say 3 resolutions mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi (today's favourites, excluding tablets - these ones deserve some folders on their own):
The graphics is going into:
res/drawable-mdpi
res/drawable-hdpi
res/drawable-xhdpi
Just put your graphics (with the **same names**) with (respectively) a dpi density of 160, 240, 320 in those directories.
Now your graphics is resolution compliant.

---

Now, I don't realize what the problem really is.
I mean, is it the **background** not fitting well? then the solution is to use a **tiling** or an "abstract enough" **stretchable** picture.
Or you could use **9 patches**, as well
If the problem is how the fonts and other objects interact with each other, you should always reference to an mdpi device (even emulated, if you don't own a physical one). When things scale well on a mdpi device, they are **supposed** to scale well on every device.
For tablets in particular, you are supposed to provide specific folders for values (where you put your dimens.xml file, containing the dimensions).
These folders normally have names like **values-sw600dp** or **values-sw720dp-land**. The suffix land indicates landscape mode, the particle sw###dp indicates the minimum dimension (width or height), so, I guess that in you case you could prepare some folders called **values-sw480dp** and **values-sw480dp-land** and there you would put your dimens.xml file, with the special dimensions for that particular device.
I guess that providing only the non-land folder would be enough.